# How to copy IPAddress class into character buffer? Getting error: "inet_ntop' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: wifi

I am using the WiFi library and trying to store the IP address in a character buffer so that I can print it out to an lcd that only accepts character buffers. My code for doing this:

```
 char * IPAD = new char[40
 IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
 Serial.println(ip);
 char * bufIP = new char[40]();
 sprintf(bufIP, "%s", inet_ntop(ip));
 lcd.string(ip);
```

But when I compile this I get the error:

```
"inet_ntop' was not declared in this scope"
```

Help?

Comment: try lcd.print(ip); lcd libraries use to implement Print and IPAddress implements Printable

Comment: My LCD library only accepts char* elements :(

Comment: then use numbers ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]

Comment: Which arduino are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IPAddress` is a class. You can't use it like a number (although in certain circumstances you can assign it to a `uint32_t` and it gives you the numeric representation).

Also, the `inet_*` functions are only really relevant on a POSIX system with a full network stack - i.e., a computer, not a little Arduino without a proper networking stack.

You can, though, easily access the individual bytes of the IP address through the `[]` operator and place them into a char array with the right format:

```
sprintf(bufIP, "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
```